# Drone won't take of nor spin its motor with Onboard SDK sample code

Tags: dji-sdk

I built up my own drone with DJI A3 and Raspberry Pi 3 with Onboard SDK 3.5. I tested the sample code and telemetry one seems ok, but flight control one didn't work. In the simulator of Assistant 2, it runs correctly, but in real life, even its motor didn't spin. here's the console log:

```
rp1:pi % ./djiosdk-flightcontrol-sample UserConfig.txt
Read App ID
User Configuration read successfully.


STATUS/1 @ init, L55: Attempting to open device /dev/ttyAMA0 with baudrate 230400...

STATUS/1 @ init, L65: ...Serial started successfully.

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L630: Device Serial No. = 0670134595

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L632: Hardware = A3

STATUS/1 @ parseDroneVersionInfo, L633: Firmware = 3.2.36.8

ERRORLOG/1 @ functionalSetUp, L211: Virtual RC not supported!

STATUS/1 @ activate, L1083: version 0x3022408

STATUS/1 @ activate, L1096: Activation successful

STATUS/1 @ startPackage, L332: Start package 0 result: 0.
STATUS/1 @ startPackage, L334: Package 0 info: freq=50, nTopics=1.
STATUS/1 @ removePackage, L441: Remove package 0 successful.
STATUS/1 @ initGimbal, L804: Gimbal not mounted!
| Available commands:                                            |
| [a] Monitored Takeoff + Landing                                |
| [b] Monitored Takeoff + Position Control + Landing             |
a

STATUS/1 @ startPackage, L332: Start package 0 result: 0.
STATUS/1 @ startPackage, L334: Package 0 info: freq=10, nTopics=2.
STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L644: %&1nZ%&̖nZ
STATUS/1 @ getCMDIDTaskMSG, L823: CONTROLLER_MOTOR_ON

ERRORLOG/1 @ initPackageFromTopicList, L162: package [0] is being occupied.
```

it seems `vehicle->control->takeoff()` returns some error(L87 in the sample code `flight_control_sample.cpp`), but I have absolutly no idea how to solve this problem.

Help is really appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem: just calibrate the compass!

the official user manual has a page with information about how to calibrate the compass.